# How to save the statement which is given in elif in a variable

Tags: python

How to save the statement which is given in  elif in a variable
Like:

```
elif 'date'in calendar:
     Date()
```

I want to save date word in a variable from elif

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date = None

...

elif 'date' in calendar:
    date = Date()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign it to variable like:

```
elif 'date' in calendar:
     date = Date()
```

Before add the remaining if part.